# Calculate required voltage in mixed circuits

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits

> **Q:** Calculate the voltage that V1 has to provide
>
> **Given:** The following circuit. The voltage through LAMP1 is 5.0V. A (U,I) chart (not shown). LAMP1 and LAMP2 are identical, non-ohmic lightbulbs.

[image: circuit]

My attempt at this problem:

LAMP1 and LAMP2 are two identical light bulbs. I know that $U(LAMP1) = 5.0 V$. According to the (U,I) chart, the value of $5.0$ V corresponds with $0.63$ A.

If $U(LAMP1) = 5.0$V, $U(R1) = 5.0$V too. That value corresponds with $I(R1) = 0.5$A.

$I(LAMP1 + R1) = 0.63 + 0.5 = 1.13$A.

Because LAMP1 and LAMP2 are identical, they are both $P = 5.0 \times 0.63 = 3.15$W lamps.

The voltage through LAMP2 has to be $U(LAMP2) = P \div I$. So $U(LAMP2) = 3.15 \div 1.13 = 2.78$V

Hence the voltage V1 has to provide is $5.0 + 2.78 = 7.8$V

Is this correct? Or am I using the wrong method(s)?

Comment: With this circuit it is impossible to operate both (identical) lamps under same conditions. It would be possible with R1 = inf. If in fact same operation conditions are impossible you have to state what you actually want (e.g. not exceed maximum ratings for any lamp). This is unclear.

Comment: @AndreasH. The lamps are identical, but they don't need to produce the same amount of light. The only condition is that U(LAMP1) is exactly 5.0V.

Comment: ok, I see. But you cant assume that both lamps dissipate the same power (that depends on operation conditions). Assuming that the light bulb is ohmic, it is the resistance that is invariant. Also there is still missing information in the question, e.g. value of R1 and behavior of the light bulb (e.g. whether it is ohmic or not).

Comment: @AndreasH. You're right, I forgot to add that both lamps are non-ohmic. The value of R1 was not given, but because there's a voltage of 5.0V, and that corresponds to an amperage of 0.5A, it had to be 5.0/0.5 = 10 Ohm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct (dissipated power is depending on operation conditions, it is not invariant).

Correct is the value of the current through LAMP2 (it is 1.13A).

You need to look up what voltage this corresponds to from the LAMP2 chart.

The voltage V1 is then 5V plus this voltage.

Comment: So U = P/I is an illegal operation? I cannot look up the value of the current in the chart, because it is out of bounds.

Comment: U = P/I is not "incorrect". The thing is that you dont know P. The P you are using is only good for voltage of 5V, but since you try to calculate V you dont know P.

Comment: If the current is out of bounds for the chart, you cant solve the problem. If this is homework, check if the numbers you used to calculate I(LAPM1+R1) are correct (calculation is valid, though).